# Tensorflow 2.2.0 :- WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables when minimizing the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

After implementing Custom Loss class as per the tensorflow api documentation and when invoking model.fit , facing this warning alongwith below error:- This is reference link on github and they have asked to raise here in stack overflow.https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42542# TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors leak out of the function building context by including a tf.init_scope in your function building code. For example, the following function will fail:

---

> @tf.function   def has_init_scope():
> my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
> with tf.init_scope():
> added = my_constant * 2 The graph tensor has name: ident33/Relu_5:0

Comment: Hi @Jaya, I saw your issue for this on Github. Thanks for posting it here too. Im running into the same problem, did you find a solution by any chance yet?